# Left Join with INNER JOIN in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question that I need to solve: I have three tables that join with inner join. However in this three table called `"products","shopping cart","purchase"`, I need to do a left join for have the lists of the user that haven't bought in the shop sistem.

For this I tried to do a left join in the entity `"products" -> "shopping cart"` and after that i tried a inner join beetwen purchase and shopping cart

RESULT? Nothing one (the system ignore the request).

My goal is to have returned all purchases NOT FACTS by users in a given time interval.

For semplify all,I enclose a copy of my Database with photo.

```
SELECT prodotti.nome_prodotto, carrello.quantita, acquisto.data_acquisto
FROM    (   subquery.prodotti prodotti
LEFT JOIN subquery.carrello carrello
    ON (prodotti.id_prodotto = carrello.id_prodotto))
        JOIN subquery.acquisto acquisto
        ON (acquisto.id_acquisto = carrello.id_acquisto)
```

I have tried this solutions:

```
SELECT prodotti.nome_prodotto, acquisto.data_acquisto, carrello.quantita   
FROM    ( prodotti 
            LEFT JOIN carrello 
            ON prodotti.id_prodotto = carrello.id_prodotto )        
INNER JOIN           acquisto 
    ON acquisto.id_acquisto = carrello.id_acquisto
```

AND

```
SELECT prodotti.nome_prodotto, acquisto.data_acquisto, carrello.quantita
FROM ( acquisto 
        INNER JOIN carrello 
            ON acquisto.id_acquisto = carrello.id_acquisto)
LEFT JOIN prodotti 
    ON prodotti.id_prodotto = carrello.id_prodotto
```

BUT NOTHING...I return a result like inner join

P.S: there you can find a copy of database and the toad file

http://www.ricetteingironelweb.it/Desktop.zip

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your `LEFT JOIN` after all your `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: I Have tried this SELECT prodotti.nome_prodotto, acquisto.data_acquisto, carrello.quantita
  FROM    ( acquisto INNER JOIN carrello ON acquisto.id_acquisto = carrello.id_acquisto)
       LEFT JOIN prodotti ON prodotti.id_prodotto = carrello.id_prodotto

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: After reading your comment, I understand the question a bit more - It sounds like you're trying to see data on items that are in the cart, but haven't been purchased in X amount of time.

To do this, `LEFT JOIN` the `purchase` table, and then use the `WHERE` clause to limit the results to a specific difference in time. Since we're using a left join, the purchase table won't always have a value, so in those cases we use `IFNULL` to specify today's date for the math (if the item in the cart still hasn't been purchased, figure out how many days from today that it's been in the cart).

```
SELECT /*products in cart*/
    prodotti.nome_prodotto
    ,carrello.quantita
FROM
    prodotti 
    INNER JOIN carrello 
        ON prodotti.id_prodotto = carrello.id_prodotto
    LEFT JOIN acquisto
        ON acquisto.id_prodotto = carrello.id_prodotto
WHERE
    /* show only items over a certain age - 5 days in this example */
    DATEDIFF((ifnull(acquisto.id_acquisto,NOW()) /* use today's date if purchase doesn't exist */
        - carrello.id_acquisto) > 5)
```

Comment: mmm..i have 3 table: "products","shopping cart","purchased" .... i need to see what the element aren't buy in X days

Comment: I've updated the response a little, hopefully it'll help a little more.